# Looking for node-sqlite3 optimization methods

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm using [sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3) wrapper for node to copy data from one db onto another while performing individual inserts in each transaction

When attempting to insert 100k entries a temporary myDB-journal file is created and updated as the query runs

The journal file keeps getting updated well after the code has finished executing in node

Electron stops responding -> memory usage jumps to ~ 1.59GB and ~120% CPU on a Mac Sierra 1.6Ghz intel core i5 (8GB rams)

**Any idea how i can optimize this process to avoid my electron app from crashing?**

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose(); 
var path = require('path');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('underscore')

module.exports.myModule = function(input){

  //the copy-from database
  var dbTarget = new sqlite3.Database(path.join(__dirname, '/db/myDB.db'));  

   // the copy-to database
   var dbSource = new sqlite3.Database(input.path); 

   // selection query that determines what to copy from the source db
    var selectionQuery = "SELECT colA, colB  FROM sourceTable WHERE colB > 0" 

    dbTarget.serialize(function() {

      // fetches all source rows
      dbSource.all(selectionQuery, function(err, rows) {

        // for each row fetched from the sourceDB
       _.each(rows,function (row) {

         // insert into targetDB if unique else ignore and move onto the next line
         var str = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `mytable` (COL_A,COL_B) VALUES(?,?)";

         //per the https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3 documentation ( prepare statement then execute)
         var stmt = dbTarget.prepare(str);

         stmt.run(input.valA,input.valB,function(err) {
           if(err) {throw err; }
         });
         stmt.finalize();
       })
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: look at BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT : just construct a str with all "INSERT". First, execute a SQL "BEGIN TRANSACTION" then execute the query string then execute "COMMIT".

Comment: @JeffProd That's a huge string to construct, doesn't look lik it would scale if i move up to 1 mil rows, No?

Comment: So do the job for example every 10,000 rows (begin transaction, inserts, commit)

Comment: @JeffProd i take it these txns can’t be concurrent, since a begin statement locks the db, right?

Comment: not sure. I think nothing is done to the db until "COMMIT".